# Content Type Hub subscriber Metadata Column value null

Tags: content-type, content-type-hub, managed-metadata-service

On a `Content Type Hub` subscriber site collection, we have site library using a `Content Type` with a `Managed Metadata` column that displays `null` if the user is not a Site Collection Administrator:

[image]

What permissions are required on the subscriber site collection to allow normal users to view the value? (Given the user full control on the root site collection didn't work). I also assume it's not the Metadata service permissions as the values are displayed fine for the user on the `Content Type Hub` publishing site (the site collection where the Content Type was created).

So it seems the permissions issue is related to the `Content Type Hub` subscriber site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://bramnuyts.be/2013/02/28/managed-metadata-column-stays-empty/) fixed my issue:

> The cause of all this trouble is a permission issue. More precisely a
>   permission issue on the TaxonomyHiddenList. The TaxonomyHiddenList
>   list can be viewed by navigating to
>   /Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx. This list contains the
>   details of all of the terms that are used in any managed metadata
>   column. When you check out the permissions of the list, you’ll
>   probably encounter only one account:
>
> Simply grant read to the NT AUTHORITYAuthenticated Users (this is
>   normally done by default):